# Jobrunr Spring Boot - How to customize Retry filter?

Tags: jobrunr

I'm using the [jobrunr spring boot starter](https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr/tree/master/framework-support/jobrunr-spring-boot-starter) version 4.0.9

How can I customize (or override) the default retry filter?

Comment: I added it as a feature request in Github. See https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr/issues/374.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now solved in JobRunr 5.0.0